# next_posts_link does not work when querying a specific category

Tags: pagination

What I am trying to do is display every post from the "News" category (in my case the "news" category's ID is 13), with 5 posts per page. The pagination links display on the page, but when I click on the 'previous' link, it will only show me the first 5 posts in the category.

The contents of page-news.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<h1 class="title">Latest News</h1>
<?php
    /*$args = array('cat' => 13);
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);*/
    global $paged;
    global $wp_query;

    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query(array('cat=13', 'paged='.$paged));

    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
?>
    <ul id="news">
<?php
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
        <li>
            <article>
                <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </article>
        </li>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
    </ul>
    <div class="news-nav">
        <?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts')); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;')); ?>
    </div>
<?php
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp;
    else :
?>
<h2>It looks like there's nothing happening at the moment.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing query string and array parameters.

They should either be a single string, like:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=13&paged=' . $paged );
```

or an array of key/value parameters, like:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => 13,
        'paged' => $paged
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried the second one, but I'm still getting the same 5 posts when I click on the previous posts link.

Comment: See HamzStramGram's answer for properly setting the `$paged` query var before you use it in the query.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: I had a closer look and the problem was due to the news page being set as the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the paged variable set using this :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

(And I don't think you need to declare it as a global before)